# MySQL Server - Node.js - MySQL Workbench connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql-workbench

I have already built a **Node.js application** which:

**The admin:**

- Log in using `localhost:3000`
- Create connection to MySQL database
- Set some rules( the changes that should be done on query received from
  user)

**The User:**

- Access using `localhost:3000/user` write some query in textbox and
  press query.
- The result of query based on rules set by admin will be displayed in other box below query textbox on the same page localhost:3000/user

**Now my question is,**
How is it possible with Node.js to make connection with **Mysql Workbench**, so that users can query using Workbench only? (I want the result of query based on rules set by admin in my Node.js application to be displayed in Workbench)

[image]

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Mysql workbench connects to a database, not to any arbitrary server platform of your choosing. If you want to restrict what users can do and see, restrict their users in MySQL itself.

Comment: @ Gimby I have see few applications which does the same. I have already installed one in my system and tried using MySQL Workbench, it works.

Comment: And what applications are these?

Comment: like Database masking tools. After installing the software I can see the result of masked data in workbench simply by "setup new connection" and then giving "Host name" and "port number" and of course mysql username and password

Comment: So other tools that interface directly with the database. They do not interface with Mysql Workbench at all.

Comment: I'm sorry can't understand what you mean